# Should low cardinality flags be indexed?

Tags: sql, performance

Let's say you have a table where a specific subset of rows is much hotter for reads. Like if there's a flag called `is_alive` for a `people` table. Or if you implement soft/logical deletes and your search criteria always includes `is_deleted = 0`.

Should these fields be included on indexes for these tables? If so, should they be more left or more right?

Let's say you have indexes like...

```
people [ last_name ]
people [ zip_code ]
people [ gender ]

widgets [ category_id ]
widgets [ seller_id ]
```

Do you make them look like

```
people  [ last_name, is_alive   ]
widgets [ category_id, is_valid ]
```

Or

```
people  [ is_alive, last_name   ]
widgets [ is_valid, category_id ]
```

The booleans themselves have low cardinality/significance unless they are paired with other search criteria.

It just feels fishy adding this field to EVERY index although it is used nearly every time. Maybe that in itself is a "problem"? Should the rows be shuttled to a different table that has the same schema? Basically partitioning on the flag.

Vendor agnostic.

Comment: `performance` and `Vendor Agnostic` should not be used together **EVER** for SQL.  How efficient something is depends 100% on that vendor's implementation.

Comment: +1 @JNK... I can give you an answer to this question for SQL Server, but it would be an answer only relevant to SQL Server...

Comment: @JNK point taken, but i was looking more for theory/rules of thumb that can be applied on a case by case basis

Answer (score 1):

One of the key ways that an index helps a query is by reducing the number of pages that need to be read for a full table scan.  Remember, the database engine is managing pages, which in turn store records.  Imagine we have a table of customers and it has an index on state.  A query that filters down to a single state only has to read a small proportion of the data.  Of course, the proportion could be like 10% (for California) versus less than 1% for a small state.  The question is:  how many pages are needed to read this data.

To answer this question we need information:  (1) how selective is the query? and (2) how many records fit on a page?  So, if 100 records fit on a page, then a query that selects 2% of the rows will almost always have to read all the pages anyway.  In this case, the index is not helping with a full table scan.  The index in turn incurs overhead, so it probably should not be used.

On the other hand, if only 1 record fits on a page, then a query that selects 2% of the rows will only have to read 2% of the pages -- a savings of 50X.  Alsmost any overhead incurred by the index is worth it.

Because indexes get used for multiple purposes, and because different databases engines implement them differently, and because page tables are implemented differently, and so on, there is no hard and fast rule.  However, I can generally say that low cardinality flags are probably not good candidates for indexes.

As I think about it, I can think of one case where an index might prove efficient.  That would be for wide rows and a queries that can be handled exclusively by the index (select flag, count(*) from table group by flag).

On the other hand, if you have several such flags, a composite index may help query performance.

Answer (score 0):

Some RBDMSs won't even let you place an index on a bit field, such as SQL Server 2000...

Something that should be vendor agnostic though... it's usually the selectivity of an index that determines its usefulness.

If you have an index on `is_alive`, and the split is 50% alive / 50% dead, then that index is not selective enough to be useful.

However, if the split is something more like 99% alive, 1% dead... then the index could be used when searching for dead people, but ignored when searching for living people.

So the index *may* be useful if there's a small percentage of rows that have a specific value for the field, *and* you search frequently enough for rows with that specific value to justify the overhead of the index maintenance.

But keep in mind, this is entirely dependent on whatever RDBMS you're using, and you should test any performance related design considerations against that specific RDBMS.