# Is a low-selectivity covering index helpful when you want to select large sections of data in a large table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, indexing

**Running On:** SQL Server 2008 R2 *Standard*. Though I imagine this is a question for all databases, not just SQL Server.

**Background:** I've always heard/read/been told that the leading edge on an index should be highly selective. This makes sense when you've got queries seeking for a particular value or small set of values -- a product id or something like that.

**General question:** are there times when a *non* highly-selective index is useful?

**For example:** I have a table with 350 million rows. The table contains a bunch of prices. The table has the following columns:

- `priceId` -- clustered index on the table
- `warehouseId` -- fk to one of 10 warehouses, equally distributed among the **150m rows**
- `algorithmId` -- fk to one of 23 algorithms for how I calculated price, equally distributed among 150m rows
- `priceDate` -- the date we last calculated the price
- `productId`

Then I run this query:

```
select productId 
from price 
where warehouseId = 1 
    and algorithmId = 1 
order by priceDate
```

**Specific question**: Wouldn't I benefit from an index like this?

```
create nonclustered index ix_p 
on price (warehouseId, algorithmId, priceDate) includes (productId)
```

It seems I would benefit b/c I've created a covering index with the filter columns nicely organized so that SQL Server can carve out huge chunks at a time and order by `priceDate`. Does that make sense? And does it work?

**Note:** I am going to try this out and will let you know what I find.

Comment: Indexing strategy almost always depends on what queries you are running. Typical viewpoints are that if you are selecting more than 10% of the data from a table, you should use a full scan or a partition rather than an index to access that data, since the index requires two disk reads - one to read the index, and another to read the data on the table...

Comment: Thanks. I've edited my question a bit b/c I meant to make clear that this is a covering non-clustered index, so no need to go back to the table. All fields are available as either key columns or included columns.

Comment: I have thought about partitioning, but I'm running 2008 standard, and I'd need to upgrade to enterprise to get the partitioning capabilities.

Comment: You don't have to partition to store data on multiple drives, nor to store indices separately. You may want to create a filegroup for your indexes if they're currently stored on the primary.

Comment: My indexes are in a separate filegroup. That filegroup has a dedicated drive, separate from primary or logging. I don't have another drive to span across right now. And that's not the question I'm asking, really.

Comment: This question's answers may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10521414/should-low-cardinality-flags-be-indexed

Comment: Additionally, if you end up creating a covering index that does this, it will almost be a copy of your table, at least in this example. So you're basically doubling your storage space.

Comment: The index you suggest will certainly allow faster results than scanning the clustered index.  Even if only because the data is in the correct order and will not need to be sorted *for this particular query*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just finished implementing a non-clustered index similar to what I describe in my question. Table had 101,308,183 rows, 61 bytes per row. Here were some results:

With current **"selective" index** with productId and warehouse as the keys:

- 461,000 Rows returned
- Average Run Time: 2 min 36 sec
- Scan Count: 116
- Logical Reads: **9,870,354**
- Physical Reads: **20,086**
- Read-ahead Reads: 967,324

With the new **non-selective index** as described in my original question:

- 461,000 Rows returned
- Average Run Time: 47 sec
- Scan Count: 76
- Logical Reads: **109,934**
- Physical Reads: **0**
- Read-ahead Reads: 1

So to summarize, a non-selective index gave me **90 times less logical reads** (9.87 million to 110k), **100% decrease in physical reads** (from 20k to 0) and a **100% decrease in read-ahead reads** (967k to 0).

Again, I believe this is because SQL already has all the data sorted, so it's very easy to cleave off (i.e. exclude) large chunks of data. Because the index covers this query (which is one of just two queries we run on it in our production environment) we don't waste time w/ key lookups.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - yes, but you basically have doubled your storage.

Long answer:

I tested this out on a SQL 2012 VirtualBox Server 2008 VM with 150 million rows of data. Filegroups were stored on the VM image, which is on a USB 3.0 connection to a solid state drive (sequential read seems to be about 250 mb/s, write about 150 mb/s).

I built a table with pseudo-random dates & productIds, with warehouseids from 1-10 evenly distributed, and algorithimids from 1-23 evenly distributed. (basically i wrote a source script component in SSIS that loaded the data).

Table storage space was about 4.7 GB, with a clustered index on primary key priceid.

Running this query:

```
select productId 
from price 
where warehouseId = 1 
    and algorithmId = 1 
order by priceDate
```

~1 million rows returned in about 30 seconds. 
Plan indicates a clustered index scan plus a sort (order by priceDate).

I then added this nonclustered index:

```
create nonclustered index ix_p 
on price (warehouseId, algorithmId, priceDate) include (productId)
```

This index is nearly as large as the table - about 4.3 GB.

Adding the nonclustered index eliminated the SORT step on the priceDate, and changed to do a nonclustered index seek to access the data. Creating this index took over 11 minutes.

Same query:
~1 million rows returned in about 4 seconds. 
Plan indicates a nonclustered index seek.

I think the biggest thing that this is doing is essentially creating two copies of your data - one in the clustered index structure, and one in the "nonclustered" structure.

I expect inserts to take about twice as long since now you have to create basically two rows for each insert.

Are you doing updates to this table on a regular basis? There may be some other strategies that may help.